# Prolog Maxmum Element in List: max_member

Tags: prolog

I want to use this function from the Sicstus library to give me the largest number in a list that is smaller than `250`. For example `[1,5,500,50]` should return `500`.
I can't make any sense from the documentary how to write `P`. 
This gives an error:

```
max_member((M < 250), M, [5,6,250,4]).
```

> `max_member(:P, ?Xmax, +[X1,...,Xn])` unifies `Xmax` with the maximum
>   element of `[X1,...,Xn]`, as defined by the comparison predicate `P`,
>   which should act like `<¯` .

Comment: What do you mean by the largest number that is smaller than 250? I would say that in [1,5,500,50] the largest number smaller 250 is 50 and not 500.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this call:

```
max_member((M < 250), M, List)
```

Is that `max_member/3` expects a predicate for the first argument that accepts two additional arguments and behaves as *less than or equal*. `max_member/3` will attempt to call `(M < 250)` as, `call((M < 250), X, Y)` which would generate an error.

The temptation then would be to write a custom comparator predicate, `compare(Ceiling, X, Y)` would would succeed if `X =< Y` only if `Y < Ceiling` or something like that. And it would be used with the call, `max_member(compare(250), X, Y)`. But such a predicate would have cases which fail regardless of the order of `X` and `Y` in the call. `max_member/3` assumes that the provided predicate, for a given pair of arguments, will fail for one ordering of the arguments, but succeed for the other. That is, it forms a "proper ordering relation" such that at least one of `call(Pred, X, Y)` or `call(Pred, Y, X)` succeeds. Otherwise, the algorithm for finding the maximum will get confused.

You can achieve what you want using two steps:

```
max_with_ceiling(List, Ceiling, Max) :-
    include(>(Ceiling), List, R),
    max_member(Max, R).
```